# Failing to install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to follow the basic "[Create a blog in 20 minutes](http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov)" Rails screencast but have hit a stumbling block already.

When I try to rake db:migrate I get errors about the gem activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter not being installed. When I try to install it, I am told it doesn't exist.

If I try to simply gem install mysql I get all sorts of madness appearing.

I am running this on Mac OS X 10.6.2 and my installation was all done through gem. My basic setup works (Hello world!).

Here is the error log:

> $ rake db:migrate (in /Users/xxxx/Sites/blog) rake aborted!
>
> Please install the jdbcmysql adapter:
>
> `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/jdbcmysql_adapter)
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>
> $ sudo gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
>
> ERROR: could not find gem activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter locally or in a repository
>
> $ sudo gem install mysql Password:
>   Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing mysql:     ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> /opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   checking for mysql_query() in
>   -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lm... yes checking for
>   mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lz... yes
>   checking for mysql_query() in
>   -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lsocket... no checking for
>   mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lnsl... no
>   checking for mysql_query() in
>   -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lmygcc... no checking for
>   mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries
>   and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log
>   file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>     --with-make-prog    --without-make-prog
>     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby
>     --with-mysql-config
>     --without-mysql-config
>     --with-mysql-dir    --without-mysql-dir
>     --with-mysql-include
>     --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
>     --with-mysql-lib
>     --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
>     --with-mysqlclientlib
>     --without-mysqlclientlib    --with-mlib
>     --without-mlib  --with-mysqlclientlib
>     --without-mysqlclientlib    --with-zlib
>     --without-zlib  --with-mysqlclientlib
>     --without-mysqlclientlib
>     --with-socketlib    --without-socketlib
>     --with-mysqlclientlib
>     --without-mysqlclientlib
>     --with-nsllib   --without-nsllib
>     --with-mysqlclientlib
>     --without-mysqlclientlib
>     --with-mygcclib     --without-mygcclib
>     --with-mysqlclientlib
>     --without-mysqlclientlib
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out

Comment: I am running into the same problem, and I just installed NetBeans yesterday.

The Java version isn't helping, and a reinstall of Rails 2.3.8 isn't working either. Does anyone know what the current fix is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like somehow or other I had two versions of rails installed. I originally did:

```
gem install rails
```

which installed 2.3.5. Then when I tried to run scaffolding it said I had the wrong version it complained and suggested I installed 2.3.5...

I did this with the command:

```
gem install -v=2.3.5 rails
```

This meant I had two (I found that out when I tried to uninstall), and for some reason it was trying to use the Ruby version... That may have been down to Netbeans using the wrong settings too.

In the end I uninstalled everything, ran:

gem install -v=2.3.5 rails

and made sure Netbeans was not trying to use JRuby as it was before. Now I have one version that doesn't complain for scaffolding or db:migrate. Sold!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have the Apple Dev Tools installed, which includes the Ruby header files.

That's what fixed it when I was running into this `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Comment: Sorry Zack you mentioned this in a Tweet and I totally forgot to reply. I have XCode installed and it's working nicely, this was a different issue. Thanks for responding though, always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter? you can do a gem activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter and installed. But AFAIK you just need it to use JDBC, normally with JRUBY. if you are using JRUBY i recommend you this site http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home

Comment: I haven't chosen to use JBury anywhere, that seems to have happened by itself. As I said I installed with $ gem install rails os OS X 10.6 so whatever that does, is what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with:

```
gem install --platform java activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
```

Realized it wasn't defaulting to the correct platform after seeing on http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter that the version was hyphenated -java.

(Did a "gem update --system" just prior.  Not sure if it had any effect on this.)

Oh and yeah, for Mysql you will need xcode and possibly additional headers to be installed for mysql.